# Regex with group captures?

Tags: java, regex

My input string can be in below forms

```
   "cust_100dept_200_address_300";
   "cust_100_dept_200_address_300";
   "dept_200_address_300cust_100";
   "address_300cust_100dept_200";
```

basically there are three attributes i.e cust,dept and address each followed by underscore and some digits.
   There sequence is flexible as i shown in my example where cust_100 can come in beginng or middle or last.

I want  the digit(i.e after underscore) for each attribute . So my expected output(whatever order of input atrributes are) is

```
   group1 = 100
   group2 = 200
   group3 = 300
```

I tried below

```
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
                "cust_(\\d+)" +
                        "dept_(\\d+)" + "address_(\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);// where input can be anything i stated in the beginning
    if (m.find()) {
      System.out.println("inside while");
      System.out.println("group1 = " + m.group(1));
      System.out.println("group2" + m.group(2));
      System.out.println("group2" + m.group(3));
    }


But i am not getting desired output?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
String customer=Pattern.compile("(?<=cust_)\\d+").matcher(input).group(0);
String department=Pattern.compile("(?<=dept_)\\d+").matcher(input).group(0);
String address=Pattern.compile("(?<=address_)\\d+").matcher(input).group(0);
```

Comment: There is no method group() that takes string as parameter undet Matcher. So exception is "The method group(int) in the type Matcher is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Comment: @emilly from Java7 regex supports named group so maybe you are using some earlier version

Comment: @Anirudh you shouldn't compare Strings with `!=`. Use `equals` method like `!"".equals(m.group("cust"))`or from Java7 `isEmpty()`

Answer (score 2):

I would do it differently

```
    String g1 = s.replaceAll(".*cust_(\\d+).*", "$1");
    String g2 = s.replaceAll(".*dept_(\\d+).*", "$1");
    String g3 = s.replaceAll(".*address_(\\d+).*", "$1");
```

Comment: the sequence of attributes is flexible!

Comment: The examples posted in the question don't have a set order. 'cust', 'dept' and 'address' could appear in any order.

Answer (score 2):

Your current regex won't correctly match the first 2 examples due to the underscores between the sections. There is also a separate issue with the second two examples where you have the sections in different order for the examples.

Your best bet would be to run the three different parts of your regex separately as three different expressions. This will allow them to extract the details regardless of the order.

The following is another alternative which will match more generally. This will allow any name/value combination. The first group will be one entire section (E.g. "cust_100") the second group would be "cust" and the third group would be "100".

```
((\w+)_(\d+)_?)+
```

[image: Regular expression image]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/7oH6ErKfgstB5IDW)

Answer (score 0):

combining strings with `+` is just the same as running them together.

I would suggest doing this as 3 different regexes, one for each pattern.

Comment: How does that resolve the asker's problem? Please post this as a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than building 3 patterns and 3 matchers I believe you will be better off having just 1 generic pattern. Consider following code:

```
String str = "cust_100_dept_200_address_300"; // your input
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)(cust|dept|address)_(\\d+)");
Matcherm = p.matcher(str);
Map<String, String> cMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
while (m.find()) {
   cMap.put(m.group(1).toLowerCase(), m.group(2));
}
System.out.printf("cMap: %s%n", cMap);
```

output in all the cases wil be:

```
cMap: {address=300, dept=200, cust=100}
```